# Camera locks and can't be unlocked

Tags: league-of-legends

I don't know what triggers this bug, but it's pretty annoying because the only thing I've found that fixes it is completely restarting the game.

Sometimes when playing my camera just locks and can neither be unlocked by the hotkey, nor by clicking the lock/unlock camera icon above the minimap.

This is really annoying, especially if it happens during a multiplayer match.

I've already tried reinstalling the game a few times to no effect; tabbing out of the game and tabbing back in sometimes fixes the problem, but not reliably.

I'm out of ideas at this point; suggestions, anyone?

Comment: In the new HUD the unlock icon is now beside the map at the bottom no longer on top. Also by the hotkey do you 'y'?

Answer (score 8):

Click and hold anywhere on the minimap and move your mouse.

Comment: This seems to work. Riot needs to fix the bug itself though. Also worth noting that it is usually triggered by locking the screen while moving your screen in the minimap in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to unlock the camera when focused on your champion, the first thing to try is by pressing the default button for unlocking the camera which is 'y'. The second is to click the locking button located beside the map in the new HUD. [image]

And lastly you can try as zETO suggests: to click and hold anywhere on the minimap then move your mouse around.

Comment: Aß mentioned in the question :"Sometimes when playing my camera just locks and can neither be unlocked by the hotkey, nor by clicking the lock/unlock camera icon above the minimap." I also tried to unlock it by moving the Cursor on the minimap but it doesnt Work :( i also recognized tat the Bug only happens on my PC and not on my laptop

Comment: You did not specify what key you were pressing and when you said the button at the top of the map I was confused because the button to unlock the camera is no longer there.

Comment: Yea i was still referencing to the old ui Layout,  i was talking About the lock/unlock Button (now) left bottom of the minimap. I was Not sure About the button because i changed all my shortcuts ingame ^^ , Problem still exists tho :(

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that bug too. There are times that I can fix it by switching to windowed mode, and then switching back to full screen. It doesn't work all the time, but its worth a shot before killing the whole client and reconnecting (or before your teammates start raging)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this bug!
The answer can be found on the blog:

[How to fix League of Legends Camera Lock Bug](http://jaredheinrichs.com/how-to-fix-league-of-legends-camera-lock-bug.html)

> Last night I finally found a reliable way of fixing the LoL Camera
> Lock bug on my machine WITHOUT having to exit the game and then
> rejoin. Please follow these steps:
>
> - On the Minimap,
> - Click AND Drag your mouse
> - If it doesn’t work try it a couple of time
> - Then click around the Mini-map.
>
> You should notice the Camera lock is now unlocked and everything is as it should!

Comment: Thanks for the link, but could you please add a summary to prevent link rot?